# Unable to import python package in AWS SAM local development

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-sam-cli, sam

I am using AWS **sam cli** to develop python application locally first.
I have used `sam build` command to install python packages mentioned in requirements.txt. Build folder is created with the dependency package folders,
But in the code, the `import` statements are showing `could not import the package.` Though it is present in the same folder as of my code.

Answer (score 0):

The Error message is show cause the imported package aren't installed as a python package since `SAM CLI` install the packages inside the project path so it can be packaged as layers and deployed in to AWS Lambda Layers